# cómo acceder a mi aplicación Vue desde una IP externa?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, ip, deployment

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación "Vue" y necesito acceder a ella desde una ip externa para comprobar su rendimiento en los dispositivos móviles. La versión de mi webpack es la 3.12.0 y mi "Vue" es la 2.5.2

```
{
 
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js --allowed-hosts 192.168.42.126",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.11.5",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.16.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "mobile-device-detect": "^0.4.3",
    "style-resources-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^2.8.1",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  }
}
```

y mi webpack.dev.conf.js

```
'use strict'
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const path = require('path')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')
const portfinder = require('portfinder')

const HOST = process.env.HOST
const PORT = process.env.PORT && Number(process.env.PORT)

const devWebpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap, usePostCSS: true })
  },
  // cheap-module-eval-source-map is faster for development
  devtool: config.dev.devtool,

  // these devServer options should be customized in /config/index.js
  devServer: {
    clientLogLevel: 'warning',
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /.*/, to: path.posix.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, 'index.html') },
      ],
    },
    hot: true,
    contentBase: false, // since we use CopyWebpackPlugin.
    compress: true,
    host: HOST || config.dev.host,
    port: PORT || config.dev.port,
    open: config.dev.autoOpenBrowser,
    overlay: config.dev.errorOverlay
      ? { warnings: false, errors: true }
      : false,
    publicPath: config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    proxy: config.dev.proxyTable,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    quiet: true, // necessary for FriendlyErrorsPlugin
    watchOptions: {
      poll: config.dev.poll,
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': require('../config/dev.env')
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(), // HMR shows correct file names in console on update.
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true
    }),
    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.dev.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

module.exports = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  portfinder.basePort = process.env.PORT || config.dev.port
  portfinder.getPort((err, port) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      // publish the new Port, necessary for e2e tests
      process.env.PORT = port
      // add port to devServer config
      devWebpackConfig.devServer.port = port

      // Add FriendlyErrorsPlugin
      devWebpackConfig.plugins.push(new FriendlyErrorsPlugin({
        compilationSuccessInfo: {
          messages: [`Your application is running here: http://${devWebpackConfig.devServer.host}:${port}`],
        },
        onErrors: config.dev.notifyOnErrors
        ? utils.createNotifierCallback()
        : undefined
      }))

      resolve(devWebpackConfig)
    }
  })
})
```

He seguido los pasos marcados para la configuración y para poder acceder desde una dirección ip, pero cuando inicio el proyecto "npm run dev" sólo me da acceso desde localhost. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Tambien he probado el comando ipconfig para tratar de acceder desde mi movil con las ip que da y solo una denominada "Default Gateway" me abre una pagina de mi servidor de internet y en la que veo los dispositivos conectados, pero no veo nada mas.

gracias a todos por su tiempo y ayuda

un saludo

Comment: tu pc tiene una ip, debes entrar por esa ip...

Comment: @gbianchi la he obtenido por el ipconfig,  pero cuando la tecleo en el navegador de mi movil esta cargando durante unos minutos y simplemente me dice que no puedo acceder. Tambien he tratado de escribirla en el navegador del propio pc en el que estoy desarollando , seguido de :8080 , como he visto en algun tutorial, pero tampoco me deja conectarme devolcviendome This site can’t be reached192.168.1.66 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED